# What is the name of this fallacy: "A is B, therefore everything is B"?

Tags: logic, fallacies

We've all heard some form of the following statements:

- "I like cookies, therefore everyone likes cookies"
- "That plane is yellow, so all planes must be yellow."
- "I have come to this conclusion, and if I have, then everyone else must have too"

The logical fallacy in these statements is: A is B, so everything is B.

Is there a name for this type of fallacy?

Comment: This is the *A is everything* fallacy.

Answer (score 5):

The name of this fallacy is a [hasty generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization#Hasty_generalization):

> Hasty generalization is an informal fallacy of faulty generalization, which involves reaching an inductive generalization based on insufficient evidence.

To answer precisely, the name of *this type* of fallacy is an [informal fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy#Informal_fallacy).